# Can't Buttons Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two buttons in my excel spreadsheet. They were both working yesterday but today when I opened my file they no longer work. I cannot click them, and if I turn on developer mode I can't select them to modify or delete them (when my mouse is over them it turns into a black cancel symbol (circle with line through it). The only thing I can think that I have done to the file between when it was working and now was moving the file to a new folder, but I've done that with other files with no problems.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Apparently my sheets had become grouped some how, and that prevented the buttons from being modified/activated.